# I know it isn't necessary to use the super() method in Java when creating a child class, but let's say that I want to use it

Tags: java, oop, parent-child

If I use the super() method, which I know it needs to be the first line in the child's constructor, would I have to use it for every following constructor? Also, when using the super() method, does that inherit every field from the parent class automatically or do I still need to initialize those fields in the child constructors? Let's say that I don't use the super() method, to inherit from the parent class, would I need to initialize the fields used in the parent class in the child class? Kind of a loaded question, this my first time asking on here. I am a student almost finished with my 2nd year so I am trying to get a good grasp on as much as I can. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. I have an example of what I'm doing below.

```
package Employee;



public class Employee {
    
    // declare employee class fields
    private String empName;
    private String empId;
    private String hireDate;
    
    // default constructor
    public Employee()
    {
        empName = "";
        empId = "";
        hireDate = "";
        
    }
    // constructor with arguments passed in
    public Employee(String name, String id, String date)
    {
        empName = name;
        empId = id;
        hireDate = date;
    }
    
    // set methods for employee class
    public void setEmpName(String name)
    {
        empName = name;
    }
    public void setEmpID(String id)
    {
        empId = id;
    }
    public void setHireDate(String date)
    {
        hireDate = date;
    }
    
    // get methods for employee class
    public String getName()
    {
        return empName;
    }
    public String getID()
    {
        return empId;
    }
    public String getDate()
    {
        return hireDate;
    }
    // create production worker class; child to employee class
    public class ProductionWorker extends Employee
    {
        private int shift;
        private double payRate;
        // default constructor
        public ProductionWorker()
        {
            super();
            shift = 0;
            payRate = 0.00;
        }
        // constructor with args passed in
        public ProductionWorker(int s, double p)
        {
            super();
            shift = s;
            payRate = p;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `super()` is the *default* invocation of the parent's class default constructor. But you can call **other** constructors. For example, `public Employee() { this("", "", ""); }`

Comment: Okay, so when I've created my second constructor to pass in arguments in the child class, I would not want to user super() because that is only for default values. Is that right?

Comment: To every constructor that doesn't explicitly have `super();` as its very first statement, the compiler adds that statement. Because of that, all your constructors have unchanged functionality if to each of them you add `super();` as their first line. If you don't explicitly declare a parent class using the `extends X` syntax, the implicit parent class is `Object`, so the `super()` that would be invoked is the default constructor of `Object`.

Comment: And `super()` doesn't have anything to do with what is inherited, whether present or absent.

Comment: That clears  it up for me. Thanks all

Comment: Somebody should bundle these comments into an Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque Somebody should close and delete the question. It's not new.

Comment: I'm new so I'm not sure how I can close this. Does it need to be answered before it can be closed?